# Android: ADB Driver for HTC Smartphones

Tags: android, adb, driver

I have been debugging on an HTC Desire for which I had the ADB drivers. Now I have been forced to debugging on an HTC Smartphones, but I can't find the driver anywhere. The standard HTC driver that used with my desire (Running Android 2.2) does not get recognized as the right driver for the HTC Smartphones (running Android ICS).

What are the other options that I have to enable launching and USB debugging on the HTC Smartphones through Eclipse Helios ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [HTCSync Version: 3.3.21](http://dl4.htc.com/managed-assets/support/software/htc-sync/htc_sync_setup_3.3.21.exe). It has USB driver also. I installed it and after that I could debug my application. Read its help [here](http://www.htc.com/au/support/content.aspx?id=185626).

Enjoy!

Comment: This should work. Maybe his version is out of date. What also sometimes happens is that Windows installs the wrong driver. For that you can go into the Device Manager in Windows, choose to update the driver for the device, and select different ones.

Comment: just the tip for people who was stuck on this problem: Enable your mobile phone in Sync Mode. Don't forget to enable USB Debugging mode on. Just connect your device with PC, and in Eclipse, you can find your device in Devices View.

Comment: kitokid, where is devices view? On my machine, I see an 'Android Virtual Device Manager', but I don't see anything else.

Comment: Note that the "HTC Driver" does not install on Windows 8 (and doesn't tell you). For these systems, you need to force the driver installation using the instructions [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13327665/588306).

Comment: @Deanna Thanks for completing the answer :)

Comment: Please provide one for Mac as well :-(

Comment: @Deanna the HTC driver from HTCSync 3.1.24.5 DID work for me on windows 8.1. I guess they fixed it.

Answer (score 19):

HTC Sync is a damn bloatware.

The latest naked drivers seem to be maintained in [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2191279).

Answer (score 13):

You can force windows to use the standard Google ADB driver by selecting "Browse my computer for driver software", browsing to the Google USB driver folder, then "Let me pick from a list of drivers on my computer". This should then let you choose "Android ADB Interface" as the driver for your non Google phone.

Once installed, this works with ADB and Eclipse development as normal.

Comment: This worked great!  I just selected ADB Composite Device v 4.x.x.x, accepted the "might not work" warning, and presto! No downloads necessary.

Comment: Once it worked and then it failed, installed [this driver](http://download.androiddrivers.net/file/HTC/HTCDriver_4.10.0.001.msi) to solve the issue.

Answer (score 11):

Here's how you can do it **without** HTC Sync bloatware:

1. Download HTC sync from http://www.htc.com/au/support/content.aspx?id=6196
2. Start the setup
3. The setup will report that some other components need to be installed first.

   If you look at the list, you'll see that the driver is part of it.
4. Press "OK", this will install the driver, some DOS boxes will flash up.
5. The actual HTC sync setup starts. **Abort the installation**.
6. Have fun! No reboot was required for me. I didn't even have to re-plug the device.

Tested on Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: probably the easiest way to ensure you've got the latest drivers and it works like a charm ( I'm using the SDK drivers at home, with no problems, but I don't wanna deal with Android SDK on my work computer and this way there are only new drivers installed ). You have to sit there and watch it say installing driver then cancel, but that should be a few seconds. If you miss it I saw above that you can uninstall HTC Sync and the driver will stay.

Comment: This! It worked great on Windows 7 64bit. I previously tried downloading just the drivers from various other sites, and all i ended up doing was breaking every other adb driver I had installed as well as the HTC one :)) But this works great, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I installed the Google Windows USB ADB Driver from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)

by following the procedure for the Nook Simple Touch. That procedure,
found is [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/BN_Nook_Simple_Touch/Installing_ADB)

have you paste the following lines into two places in the `adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf` file:

```
; HTC One X
%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0CED
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0CED&MI_01
```

Then I had to kill the ADB server and restart it.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce one confusion.

As mentioned above in the answers For Windows 7 64-bit I used the following link:
http://androiddrivers.net/htc-android-drivers/download-htc-one-x-64-bit-windows-drivers/

Though when you extract the files the driver is contained within Vista_x64 folder. This is confusing but it installs perfectly fine under Windows 7. I can now easily debug my application on HTC-One X.

Steps for installing the driver:
1. Right Click on Computer -> Properties
2. Click Device Manager in the Left hand pane
3. Find your HTC Device under USB Devices or Android USB Devices.
4. Right Click -> Update Driver
5. Locate the extracted directory containing the driver i.e "HTC_Driver_64\HTCDriver\Driver Files\Vista_x64"
6. Click Next and install the driver.

Comment: Broken link, androiddrivers.net no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who don't want to install the HTC bloatware, I extracted the USB driver from the package and hosted it on my website a while back, I hope it helps anyone who may still be struggling.

[windows 7/8 htc android usb driver](http://www.hassang.com/htc-usb-driver-for-windows-8-and-possibly-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

Though when you extract the files the driver is contained within Vista_x64 folder. This is confusing but it installs perfectly fine under Windows 7. I can now easily debug my application on HTC-One X.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the driver-only for download anywhere. I connected the device and it asked to  install the HTC Sync Manager, which installed the driver. But, the Sync Manager was conflicting with ADB - it kept shutting it down for some reason. So, I uninstalled the sync manager. That left the drivers in place. After re-connecting the device, adb worked.

Answer (score 0):

the people who are facing the problem in connecting their htc phone with eclipse. they must install HTC-SYNC from the htc site. htc sync also include the usb debugging driver in it.

Here's the link: http://www.htc.com/au/support/content.aspx?id=6196

Answer (score 0):

I've installed HTC sync Manager this and it recognized the phone.

http://www.htc.com/us/support/software/htc-sync-manager.aspx