# ADT not detecting HTC One in debug mode

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have recently installed the official update to Android 4.3/Sense 5.5 for my HTC One, and now when I try to run my Android applications via ADT it doesn't recognize my device anymore. One thing I noted to be different than the previous version is that it now starts with the debug mode right away, and the option to enable/disable it to use HTC Sync is gone. So I have tried enabling the Developer options to disable debugging and enable it again, nothing happened - the phone says "USB debugging connected" but ADT won't detect it.

My projects' Target SDK are all set to 18 and min SDK 11 and they were running before when my phone had Android 4.2.2/HTC Sense 5.

Has anyone experienced the same problem lately? I tried to find similar issues but since this upgrade is recent for HTC One then maybe not many people had this issue yet...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try resetting your adb

Comment: which OS you are working linux or windows?

Comment: @BirajZalavadia I'm running Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the version problem causing the damage for you..
 see the answer below it would help you...

[Android: ADB Driver for HTC One X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012944/android-adb-driver-for-htc-one-x)

Comment: So I uninstalled the drivers I had and installed this version, it didn't work. However, when the phone launched again it told me there was a driver update available (it didn't show me that before). I installed the version suggested by the phone and now it works, so I'll accept your answer as it sent me the right way. Thanks!